# What equation should I use to calculate inductance of a wire coil?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-circuits, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

I've been working on a project recently which requires me to build an inductor, however in my research I found many different equations (with a range of variables used and giving very different results to the same coil specifications) and I was wondering what equation I should use. I have attached some links below to sites with different equations on them.

https://sciencing.com/calculate-inductance-coil-6026538.html

https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/coil-inductance-calculator/

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple, exact formula for this. What you are looking at in the first two links are a couple of approximations. For a comprehensive treatment of this subject, see [this document](http://g3ynh.info/zdocs/magnetics/Solenoids.pdf) by David Knight.